# Checking the result of a method in if statements using jsf

Tags: jsf, el

Can I check the return value of a method directly in if statement like this?

```
<h:form>
<c:if test="#{bidBean.searchbyproperty(property.propertyId) == 'n'}">
   <p> no result </p>
</c:if>
</h:form>
```

If no how can I check the value in my xhtml file ?

Comment: did you try it like thie `#{managedBean.condition = ? 'execute something' : null `

Comment: Did you try to do so?

Comment: yeah but the problem is the method which is being called, my checking value is not direct like bean.var  , it's the return value of a method like, bean.method(var), it gives an error

Comment: Errors represent answers in their entirety. It's a matter of being able to understand them. We are able to translate them in layman's terms. As long as you ignore error messages, no one will be able to explain them to you. At least, the code syntax looks fine, but this construct can theoretically fail due to numerous possible causes which we can't exclude based on the information provided so far.